# Export certificate in windows store to a p12 file using Java

Tags: java, certificate, pkcs#12

I will need to export a certificate in windows store to a p12 file. Similar to what you can do from firefox/IE browser but in JAVA. The only way I am able to do it currently is doing a C# with double Cpp wrappers or MCPP with wrapper using JNI which is not really useful. I have tried using SUNMSCAPI but I was not able to.. Any inputs appreciated.. Thank you..

If the above is certainly not possible, can a keystore be created with these certs?

Comment: Any help with not using .net framework/JNI please

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Java standard keystore API, with [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html). You can load the keystore called `Windows-MY`, that contains all the certificates stored in the Windows keystore.

```
KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
```

The reference to the Windows keystore provides method to extract certificates, via the [`KeyStore.getCertificate(String alias)` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getCertificate%28java.lang.String%29).

Once you retrieved the certificate, export it to a PKCS12 file.

Comment: I remember trying this.. Are you sure it will allow me to export the private key as well? Will try it tomorrow

Comment: As far as I know, it will export the private key as well.

Comment: `code`  KeyStore keystore3;
  try {
   Provider bcProv = Security.getProvider("BC");
   if (bcProv == null)
   {
    // Instantiate the Bouncy Castle provider
    Class<?> bcProvClass = Class.forName("org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider");
    bcProv = (Provider) bcProvClass.newInstance();

    // Add BC as a security provider
    Security.addProvider(bcProv);
   }

   keystore3 = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "BC"); `code`
throws a no such algorithm: Windows-MY for provider BC

Comment: I am able to load the windows store using SunMSCAPI, but it does not allow me to export the entire entry

Comment: Tried to export with the below code,    
openedKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
Key privKey = openedKeyStore.getKey(sEntryAlias, cPassword);
Certificate[] certs = openedKeyStore.getCertificateChain(sEntryAlias);
KeyStore pkcs12 = KeyStoreUtil.createKeyStore(KeyStoreType.PKCS12);  // Create a new PKCS #12 keystore using BC provider
pkcs12.setKeyEntry(sEntryAlias, privKey, new char[0], certs);
pkcs12.store(fos, cPassword);
java.io.IOException: exception encrypting data - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Cannot wrap key, null encoding.

Comment: Awarding the bounty for the help provided.